# Set a default build configuration for project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I have several possible configurations in a Visual Studio project file. How can I specify which one is selected by default (when no `.suo` is present)? Right now, when I open the project in Visual Studio, Debug configuration is selected by default.

Relevant part of the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>...</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>...</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{...}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>...</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>...</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>AAAAA</AssemblyName>
    <MyType>Windows</MyType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>Bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>AAAAA.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>AAAAA.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I want this configuration to be selected by default:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
    <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
    <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>Bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <DocumentationFile>AAAAA.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Not sure but try changing this like `<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>` to `<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Visual Studio always invokes the build through a solution. Each solution configuration has a (case-insensitive) name and maps each project to its configuration. Solution configurations can be edited through *Build > Configuration manager* and the currently active one is selected there or in the drop-down in the toolbar.

## Which solution build configuration is used?

Active build configuration is saved in solution user options file (`.suo`). This is a per-user configuration and should not be checked in the source control. No shared configuration exists for this.

If no `.suo` file is present, VS selects the configuration, whose name sorts alphabetically first with several exceptions:

- All names starting with "Debug" sort before "A".
- *S1*␣*S2* sorts before *S1* for any two strings *S1* and *S2*. (␣ denotes a space.)

E.g. if you have this list of configurations, "Debug all" is selected by default. If you remove the first configuration in the list, close VS and delete the `*.suo` file, the next one on the list will be selected by default.

```
Debug all
Debug
Debugging
A release
ARelease
Release
WinterBash
```

Note that VS displays a different order:

```
A release
ARelease
Debug
Debug all
Debugging
Release
WinterBash
```

## Which solution is used?

If you open a project file (e.g. `MyProject.csproj`) directly, Visual Studio tries to locate a solution file.

1. Solution with the same name in the same directory (`MyProject.sln`) is preferred. If it is found, it is used.
2. Any other solutions in the same directory (`*.sln`) are searched. If *exactly one* is found, it is used.
3. The parent directory is searched for any solutions (`..\*.sln`). If *exactly one* is found, it is used.
4. Otherwise, VS creates a new solution (named `MyProject.sln`) containing only the project and asks on exit where to save it. This new solution's build configurations correspond to the ones the project has.

<sup>Note that this is probably going to be different in the upcoming VS 2017 as it supports even bare files without projects.</sup>

You can see the path to the solution as *Path* in Properties window. (Select the solution in Solution Explorer first.)

---

By the way, the first `PropertyGroup` in a project file specifies the defaults to be used by MSBuild when `Configuration` and `Platform` properties are empty (unspecified). Visual Studio always specifies these properties, so the defaults are irrelevant.

Comment: Do you know if S1.S2 sorts also before S1 for any two strings S1 and S2? It seems to me that way. I have the configurations Debug.Custom and Debug. When I clone the solution and open VS Debug.Custom is selected.

Comment: @dyedwiper, I have no time to test that but it seems even period character may be treated just like space. Wonder how they sort relatively, i.e. what is the order of "Debug Custom" versus "Debug.Custom". I have no official source for the sorting part of the answer, I remember figuring it out by trial and error and it takes some time to create the project and solution required to test this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the build configurations are listed alphabetically. Meaning the "Debug" configuration will be the default item. And "Release" will not be. If you wish Release to be the default configuration you can create a new build configuration and ensure it is displayed before "Debug", by using the alphabetic sorting, e.g. name the build configuration "ARelease".
Not a perfect solution, but it works.

Comment: It doesn't use alphabetical order. It prefers Debug or names starting with Debug by default if there is no .suo file. For example, Debug configuration will be selected even if there is configuration with name "ARelease"