# Change the Default VS configuration Manager option

Tags: visual-studio

In my team we are building Visual Studio projects targeting 3 different environments:  DEV (development), QA (quality assurance) and PROD (production)

The configuration manager allows me to create the 3 environments for an existing project, but as we add more projects, we need to remember to manually switch the default "Debug" and "Release" configurations.  Is there a way to permanently change the default start up config to DEV/QA/PROD, so it can be applied to all my teams ?

Below is the default
[image]

And here is the (hoped for version)
[image]
Any suggestions are welcomed..

Thanks!

Comment: I hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33744624/set-a-default-build-configuration-for-project/41445987#41445987  also  https://aras-p.info/blog/2017/03/23/How-does-Visual-Studio-pick-default-config/platform/

Comment: This partially helps.   The challenge for my team is that we're frequently creating new projects all the time.  having to change the config environment everytime is a pain, and prone to error.  What would be the answer i'm looking for is to permanently change the "Debug/Release" default to "DEV/QA/PROD" so when a new project/solution is created, it starts with the new values..

Comment: In that case, you need to create your own project templates and then package them in your own Visual Studio extension and install them in all of your developers workstations.  Then when your developers start a new project you select YOUR TEAM'S project template instead of Microsoft's Visual Studio project template.

Comment: That was too easy..  Should have remembered that..  Thanks!